# Wigner function in relation to real space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, dipole, quasiprobability-distributions

The Wigner function is a quasi-probability distribution because it can have values of $x$ from -1,0,+1.  As it is orthogonal to the $x,p$ plane can this be represented as a dipole moment along the $z$ access in Hilbert space, or is it along the $x$ axis?

If along the $x$ axis (which I think is right) then would a further instance of a superposition THEN be orthogonal to that dipole and align along the $z$ axis?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: incorrect.  The values of $x$ (or $p$) are unrestricted and continuous but the WF can take negative values (depending on the state if you compute the WF for a state).  The values of the ordering parameter $s$ are continuous from -1 to 1 and have a physical interpretation in terms of common orderings for $s=-1,0$ and $1$

Comment: Thanks ZTH - appreciate this correction.